# PhpStorm - change Live Templates location

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I've created some useful Live Templates in PhpStorm on my PC at work.

Nothing exciting so far, but I'd like to take those live templates with me at home as well, as I am using PhpStorm on my Mac as well.

I know that there's the possibility to export the live templates to a `.jar` file and then import them again, but I was wondering if there was a better solution (one that doesn't include export/import every time you make a change).

My Idea was the following:

Can I change the path that PhpStorm uses to locate live templates to a different folder? My idea is to then share this folder to my PC and my Mac (almost certainly as a Dropbox folder) and then I don't have to worry about live templates anymore, as they will be loaded from the Dropbox shared folder automatically and always be up to date.

Is this possible in any way?

Do you have alternative solutions to achieve the same result that you would like to share here as well?

Comment: You can try symlinking the "templates" folder .. but it may not work super well (might be some nuances from Dropbox/Google Drive side). Other than that -- have a look at standard Settings Repository plugin.

Comment: *"as they will be loaded from the Dropbox shared folder automatically and always be up to date."* keep in mind -- IDE setting files are not read on change -- only on IDE startup. Similar kind of story with writing them -- if you modify a config file while IDE is still running, then it most likely will be overwritten with latest in-memory/currently-running config on IDE exit. If you will have only 1 IDE active at a time (I mean: home or work) then this should not be an issue.

Comment: @LazyOne is sorry I meant not real time but on startup. The main idea is: weekdays I use my pc at work and I may create new live templates, if during the weekend I open phpstorm at home I don't have to worry about those templates as they should (hopefully) be loaded on phpstorm when it started. Also, can you elaborate a bit more on the Settings repository plugins? what you mean with this?

Comment: just to clarify, is this article referring to the folder that also stores the live templates? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage

Comment: 1) https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7566-settings-repository 2) I'm not using Dropbox .. but when I did try it (like 7 or so years ago) I think I could add individual folders (any location). So in theory (If I'm correct) you can just add the folder to the "sync by Dropbox" list and it might be enough. 3) No that article - more [this one](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519). So on Windows it would typically be `C:\Users\USERNAME\.PhpStorm2017.1\config\templates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I followed [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-and-ide-settings.html) that gives me an easy to understand explanation about what each folder contains and then I decided to symlink the folder I want to share and everything seem to work just fine (so far).

Thanks to @LazyOne to mention the Symlink idea :)